# Mean square convergence

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

I am working on an example in my book and cannot figure out an expectation.

Let
$$E(T_n)= \frac{n\theta}{n+1}$$
$$E(T_n^2)= \frac{n\theta^2}{n+2}$$
$$g(t)=\frac{nt^{n-1}}{\theta^{-n}}$$

Then
$$E((T_n-\theta)^2)=\frac{2\theta^2}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

I have tried breaking it up into

$$E(T_n^2) - 2\theta E(T_n)+\theta^2$$

as well as integration

$$E((T_n-\theta)^2)= \int_0^\theta t^2\frac{nt^{n-1}}{\theta^n}\mathrm{d}t-\theta$$

but whatever I do I cannot seem to get the Expectation to equal the above. Does anyone know how to do so?

Comment: The fourth line needs a negative sign.  The last line makes little sense: what is $\theta$ doing, subtracted off like that?  (I took the liberty of inserting a $\mathrm{d}t$ in order to make sense of it.)  Watch out for typographical errors in the book!

Comment: alright, I have clarified it

Comment: At least two errors remain: (1) the expression for your PDF has the wrong normalizing constant (and it should also specify that $0\le t\le \theta$) and (2) that mysterious $-\theta$ is still dangling off the end of the integral. Do you perhaps mean to integrate $(t-\theta)^2$?

Comment: I am trying do find the $E((T_n-\theta)^2)$, would integrating $(t-\theta)^2$ accomplish that?

Comment: That is an application of the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=Law+of+the+unconscious+statistician).  Of course by "integrating" we both mean *against the PDF of $t$* and not just the (ordinary) Lebesgue integral!

Comment: The easiest is $E(T_n^2) - 2\theta E(T_n)+\theta^2$ - and it does give the correct answer -just be careful with the algebra.

Comment: We can't identify where you went wrong if you don't show us what you did.